# scaffold command does not work with Rails 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate a Rails app with the Scaffold command as in every beginner's tutorial:

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

I'm getting this junk:

```
>     Usage:
>       rails new APP_PATH [options]
>     
>     Options:
>       -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
>                                                              # Default: /Users/etayluz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
>       -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you create the app first? `rails new app_name`

Comment: You need to create a Rails app first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a rails app with the scaffold command. First create a new rails application using

```
rails new app_name
```

then use the scaffold command to generate the migration file, model, controller etc